# Laravel and two way SSL over specific laravel routes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, ssl

Trying to set up a two way SSL connection between two production servers. A client machine will connect to a Laravel route with a certificate and pass an xml payload. There should be a two way ssl handshake between the apache server on the production machine and the client machine.

I'm using this apache Directory setting on the production machine:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/subdomain/html/routename>
    SSLVerifyClient      require
    SSLVerifyDepth       5
    SSLOptions           +FakeBasicAuth
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire       %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "company name"
    SSLCipherSuite    ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
</Directory>
```

I've set the following in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        SSLOptions +ExportCertData

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The Laravel route is still accepting connections from machines that are not using certificates at all or with certs meeting the SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O requirement. Seems the mod_rewrite is taking precedence over the Directory ssl requirement. Thank you in advance for aAny basic advice. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I'm new at 2-way ssl with PHP. Are you suggesting the dual ssl handshake between the two machines can happen inside the php application code and not at the server level?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on this option.

Laravel works by hijacking urls through a "rewrite" in the hidden .htaccess file. If the url location actually exists then apache will process the script on the file system. If the url location does not exist on the filesystem then the rewrite will route the request through Laravel's controllers (routes.php), process, and return.

The apache location and directory directives work with specific scripts in specific file system locations. I need those directives to protect certain scripts from being executed except by visitors presenting a specific SSL client certificate. That architecture is basically incompatible with the way Laravel is structured.

As a work around I created specific scripts (php files) in actual file system locations, protected them with an apache location directive, and forwarded the incoming requests to Laravel routes that expected requests to come from localhost.